# Function that creates list of personalia

Tags: matlab, function, text

I have the function

```
fid = fopen(filename,'w');

if exist('fid')
    check = true;
else
    check = false;
end


for i=1:length(persons)   
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n',serialize_person(persons(i)));
end
end
```

Where serialize_person is

```
function [output] = serialize_person(person)

fprintf ( '<%s>#' , person.name ) ;
serialize_date ( person.date_of_birth ) ;
fprintf ( '#<%i>\n' , person.phone ) ;

end
```

Which takes is a personalia and writes out 'name.day.month.year.phonenumber'
Firstly I need to make this come out as a single string of text in 'output' for it  to(I assume)work in the first function, how would I go about this?

Secondly, the first function takes is a filename and a cell of persons. I want it to come out on a textfile with the name 'filename' with one personalia per line.
Yesterday I had it working up to the for loop, but somehow I cant get beyond the first line today without hitting an error message.
Could you give me some advice here, I don't know whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To write output to a character array rather than the console, use `sprintf`. Also, to join the strings with a `'.'` between strings, try `strjoin` with a delimiter set:

```
function [output] = serialize_person(person)
    delim = '.';
    output = strjoin(sprintf ( '<%s>#' , person.name ), ...
                     serialize_date ( person.date_of_birth ), ...
                     sprintf ( '#<%i>\n' , person.phone ), delim);

end
```

Modify `serialize_date` similarly.